# LARAVEL Post Method shows token on address bar

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to insert data to the database using post method, but instead of inserting it does nothing and token appears on the address bar of my web browser.

This is what's showing:

http://localhost:8000/missions/dupe/1?_token=hd0xhTVvYYBBlIpJ2smCv6x5AmOG2AVCgtGIpDNP&personnel_id=5&services_booth_id=1

Here's my form looks like:

```
                            <li class="list-group-item">
                                <form action="/booth_personnel/create" method="post">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                      <select class="form-control" name="personnel_id">
                                        @foreach($personnel as $person)    
                                        <option value="{{$person->id}}">{{$person->full_name}}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                                      </select>
                                      <input type="hidden" value="{{$service->id}}" name="services_booth_id">            
                                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" tabindex="-1"><span aria-hidden="true"></span>Add Personnel</button>
                                      </span>
                                    </div>

                                </form>
                            </li>
```

Here's my Route:

```
Route::post('/booth_personnel/create', 'BoothPersonnelController@store');
```

My Controller:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'personnel_id' => 'required',
        'services_booth_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    $result = BoothPersonnel::addNew($request);
    if($result === true) {
        $message = "Successfully added to database.";
        return redirect()->back()->with('formSuccess', $message);
    } else {
        return back()->withErrors($result);
    }

}
```

My Model:

```
   public static function addNew($request){
    $result = array();
    DB::beginTransaction();

    try {
        $current_time = Carbon::now('Asia/Manila');
        DB::insert("INSERT INTO `tbl_booth_personnels`
            (
                `personnel_id`, `services_booth_id`, `created_at` 
            ) 
            VALUES 
            (?, ?, ?)",
                   [
                       $request->input('personnel_id'),
                       $request->input('services_booth_id'),
                       $current_time
                   ]
                  );

        DB::commit();
        $result = true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        $result = $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Note: I'm looping I have a multiple form inside my view, it it inside a foreach method. It only happens on the first loop, the next one's inserting just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I have another form tag wrap outside the loop.
I deleted it and everything now works fine.

Answer (score 0):

simply change this {{ csrf_field() }} to this {{Form::token()}}

Comment: that didn't do anything, it still generate token on the address bar for the first loop.